# can /boot be on a different drive than grub or lilo?

Tags: boot, grub, ssd, lilo

I just got a vizio CN15-A5 laptop, which has both a 1TB HDD and a 32G SDD. I am going to use the SSD with dm-cache, however, I would to make /boot a partition on the SSD, and the laptop's BIOS doesn't support booting off of the SSD.

Before I make my system unbootable on accident...can GRUB or LILO be installed on on /dev/sda and fire up /boot from /dev/sdb? Do you think it would improve boot time much or at all?

Comment: What do you mean the bios doesn't support booting off the ssd?

Comment: It doesn't. Boot options are USB and HDD and network. Maybe there will be a BIOS update for that eventually, but it was intended to be an SSD cache so I guess the didn't expect anyone would want to boot off of it.

Comment: An SSD looks like a HDD as far as the bios knows.  If it can boot from a HDD it can boot from the SSD.

Comment: Yes, but they are in different SATA ports and the bios only knows how to boot from one. Since its a laptop, you cannot physically swap which ports the drives are plugged into. A BIOS is not a standard, it can be written however the manufacturer wants, and in this case they saved time by not supporting booting off of both drives in the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do that but your not going to be saving much time. If the BIOS doesn't "see" the drive at that part of the boot process then your going to have a hard time storing stage2 on the drive (not that it would be easy in the first place).

You will be better served by putting /boot on HDD. It's much easier, and it's not like those files are read frequently. Once booted, the computer never uses them (except when updating grub or other boot stuff). Your not really going to gain any speed by having boot on the SSD.